# Insert PHP value as array member?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm having a problem with inserting previously defined PHP value $video_url as one of the array members. Here the code:

```
$video_url= "[[+virtual_tour]]"; /* [[+virtual_tour]] is MODX placeholder which contains first video url */

echo $video_url; /* for test reasons. Outputs https://youtu.be/9bZkp7q19f0 */

$url = array(
'$video_url', /* URL of the first video */
'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e-ORhEE9VVg' /*URL of the second video */
);
// Extracts the YouTube ID from various URL structures
foreach ($url as $value) {
    if (preg_match('%(?:youtube(?:-nocookie)?\.com/(?:[^/]+/.+/|(?:v|e(?:mbed)?)/|.*[?&]v=)|youtu\.be/)([^"&?/ ]{11})%i', $value, $match)) {
        $id = $match[1];
echo $id; /* outputs only ID of second video, but not first */
    }
}
```

So I have something word by inserting $video_url into array. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try without quotes around `$video_url`:

```
$url = array(
   $video_url, /*URL of the first video**/
   'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e-ORhEE9VVg' /* URL of the second video */
);
```

Single quotes [do not interpolate](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single) strings, meaning the value of `$url[0]` is literally `$video_url`.

Also, take care with comments, in PHP they are not `#`.

Comment: Tried without quotes, the same result

Comment: Are you fix your comments? Remove `#` and add `//`. Can you `var_dump($url)` to know what is inside it?

Comment: I've fixed comments (and in my original post).

Here is var_dump($url) result:

array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(17) "https://youtu.be/9bZkp7q19f0"
  [1]=>
  string(43) "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e-ORhEE9VVg"
}

Comment: It works like a charm: https://regex101.com/r/kW7jM2/1 . Why the second URL have 43 characters?

Comment: have no idea about 43 characters

Comment: I think you have another code that makes conflicts or transform something in the behaviour. The code, as this, must work perfectly. Can you make a phpfiddle to show us the working example? http://phpfiddle.org/

Comment: I make a phpfiddle.org with your code with my changes and the result is fine: `9bZkp7q19f0<br>
e-ORhEE9VVg`. For sure you've got any code that makes conflicts. http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/smf9-xzuh

Comment: maybe some conflict comes from that my php code is inside MODx snippet..

Comment: I don't know what is MODx but you need to parse the string before the loop with preg_match(). This is the correct answer since the problem of the array is resolved with this solution, but if you don't provide us more explanation of your problem we can't help you better.